# Android Facebook Login Firebase invalid hash key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

So recently I was trying to log in to my android application using Facebook login. I followed all the instructions (generating key, putting it on Facebook, etc...) but even after I completed all the steps I still couldn't login.

I got two problems:

1. "Facebook Login Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook"
   [image]
2. "Invalid hash key when trying to login using Facebook" - a. From application installed by Android studio. b. From application installed by Play Store.
   [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of research I found the solutions:

1. Because during the search someone proposed to delete my app from Facebook and recreate it again, the AppID and AppSecret on Facebook changed and I didn't Update the Firebase console accordingly.
   [image]
2. a. I generated the key using next code:

   ```
   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                   "com.example.somepackage",
                   PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }
   } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

   }
   ```

   I went to logcat, copied the generated key and inserted it to Facebook application
   [image]
   After this I was able to log in while debugging my application.

   b. After I uploaded the app on Play Store I was surprised to see that I am not able to log in using Facebook! To fix this I found next solution:
   Go to Firebase -> Project Settings copy each of SHA fingerprint you have, paste it to [Convert Hexadecimal to base64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php), get the result from base64 line and add it to Facebook (in addition to the key from "2.a.").[image][image][image]

Comment: Your solution worked. I just want to highlight, even if you updated firebase console with the new App ID and App Secret.. the generated hashkey would still not be the updated. Upon some googling, it's some sort of bug. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798217/why-keytool-is-generating-different-facebook-androiddebugkey-hash

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happend to me while I was integrating firbase Auth.UI for facebook.
for some reason the key generated output doesn't match with the actual key generated.
this is for Linux users and on development environment
cd into app-debug.apk to`cd /buil/outputs/apk/debug`
enter `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile .app-debug.apk`

you will be promted with
`Certificate fingerprints:
   MD5: xx:xx:xx.......
   SHA1: xx:xx:xx....... 
   SHA@56: xx:xx:xx.......`

copy SHA1 values and change it to base64(you can use any tool) you will get the right key hash which you will add to your key hashes on facebook app settings.