# Trying to get Release Key Hash for Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am developing an *Android* application, where I am using a `Facebook` login button.
Firstly I have created *Signed release APK* from an *Android* studio and created new keystore. Then I tried to create **Release Key Hash** for my application, with *OpenSSL*. That's the command I have used:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias facebook -keystore ...\keystore.jks | D:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | D:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

Afterwards, I was asked for a password, here I have provided the password that I have generated when creating *Signed release AP*K.
I copy the key, that was provided from the console and copied it to Key hashes input in facebook console. 
However, whenever I try to use facebook login, I got the error:

```
Invalid key hash. The kay hash ...... does not match any stored hashes...
```

If I copy the key that is provided in error to facebook console, it works as it should, but I don't want to do that for each person that will use my application, do I?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was able to fix it by following instructions from [Why keytool is generating different facebook androiddebugkey hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798217/why-keytool-is-generating-different-facebook-androiddebugkey-hash)

Also I had missed to set the my application's status from development to live in Facebook console.

Comment: Isn't this approach to gather hash for developing mode, or it is just a matter of which keystore you choose(whether you choose debug.keystore or keystore that you have created) where My app is set as live in facebook console.

Comment: If you run your app in debug then you get a debug hash key and if you run it with 'release' build variant then you get a release key. And this key is the key you need to enter in your Facebook developer console. The one that is created by keytool doesn't seem to be correct. Some suggested that might be a bug.